# Bash expr output issue

Tags: linux, bash, math

I am taking a course that has the following script in a lab:

```
#/bin/bash
#
# arithmeticLab
# demonstrates arithmetic, functions and simple if clauses
# three methods are used for arithmetic.
# the exercise requires only one.
# the three methods are:
# 1) let
# 2) expr
# 3) $((...))
# The user will input a letter and two numbers.
# the letter will
# be a(dd), s(ubtract), m(ultiply), d(ivide)
# to select an 
# arithmetic operation.

# Functions. must be before the main part of the script
# 
adder() {

# method 1. use let
let answer1=($fNumber + $sNumber)

# method 2. use expr
answer2="expr ${fNumber} + ${sNumber}"

# method 3. use $((...))
answer3=$(($fNumber + $sNumber))

} # end adder function
#--------------------------------

subtracter() {

# method 1. use let
let answer1=($fNumber - $sNumber)

# method 2. use expr
answer2='expr $fNumber - $sNumber'

# method 3. use $((...))
answer3=$(($fNumber - $sNumber))

} # end subtracter function

#---------------------------------------

multiplyer() {

# method 1. use let
let answer1=($fNumber * $sNumber)

# method 2. use expr
answer2='expr $fNumber * $sNumber)'

# method 3. use $((...))
answer3=$((fNumber * $sNumber))

} # end multiplyer function

#-------------------------------------

divider() {

# method 1. use let 
let answer1=($fNumber / $sNumber)

# method 2. use expr
answer2='expr $fNumber / $sNumber'

# method 3 use $((...))
answer3=$(($fNumber / $sNumber))

} # end divider function
# End of functions
# 

# Main part of the script
# check that user provided a letter and two numbers
# does not checkt o see if the user put in
# an incorrect letter 
# which wil simply display messages without an answer

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: Provide an operation (a,s,m,d) and two numbers"
    echo "Syntax: "$arithmetic.sh s 40 2" will produce output of "40 - 2.""
    echo "" 
    exit 1
fi

#-----------------

# set the input number to variables to pass to the functions
#

fNumber=$2
sNumber=$3

if [[ $1 == "a" ]]
    then
        adder
fi

if [[ $1 == "s" ]]
    then
        subtracter
fi

if [[ $1 == "m" ]]
    then 
        multiplyer
fi

if [[ $1 == "d" ]]
    then 
        divider
fi

#-------------------------------
# Present the answers for all three methdos
#

echo "Method 1 Answer is $answer1"
echo "Method 2 Answer is $answer2"
echo "Methdo 3 Answer is $answer3"
```

This produces an output as `Method 2 Answer is expr $fNumber - $sNumber` instead of `Method 2 Answer is expr 20`, for example.

The input should be something like `script.sh m 30 50 to multiply 30 by 50` or `script.sh s 70 30` to subtract 30 from 70.

I tried using double quotes, single quotes and { brackets in the answer2=expr... lines without success.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Putting backticks before and after each line makes your code nearly unreadable. To mark a block of text as a code section, select it in the editor and click the `{}` button, which will indent each line by four characters, having the requisite effect.

Comment: Also, please try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- describing how to build a *minimal*, *complete*, *verifiable* example for any question.

Comment: ...so, if you're having a problem with `expr`, show only the parts that involve `expr`, and remove anything (like the user input and validity checking and so forth) that isn't necessary to demonstrate that problem. (Sure, you need to have values to operate on, but values can be hardcoded).

Comment: I'll edit it right now. Thanks

Comment: @Charles Duffy I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using double quotes "".

Change your lines from:

> ```
> answer2="expr ${fNumber} + ${sNumber}"
> ```

To:

> ```
> answer2=$(expr ${fNumber} + ${sNumber})
> ```

Comment: Better would be `expr "$fNumber" + "$sNumber"`

Comment: For `answer2=$(expr ${fNumber} * ${sNumber})`, this did not produce any output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I changed the multiplyer to expr "$fNumber" * "$sNumber" and it still did not product an output. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the problem that he's using *single* quotes for all but the first function?

Comment: @Debug255, you need to quote the `*` too. Otherwise it's replaced with a list of filenames.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: ...and, yes, the single quotes are definitely a problem. @Debug255, perhaps you were trying to follow examples that used backticks instead of single-quotes with expr? But the best-practice approach is `$()`, not backticks either. (Well, best-practice is to use `$(( ))`, not expr either).

Comment: @Debug255, alternately:  
    answer2=$(expr $fNumber \\* $sNumber)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The `\` escape before the `*` is good too. I guess the goal is to use the way that works on the most systems, so whether I am using Mac, Ubuntu, CentOS, or OpenSUSE, or most bash shells, the script will work.